# How to prove binomial coefficient is asymptotic big theta of two to the power n?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, binomial-coefficients

I am stuck at this problem. I think it is equivalent to show 2m choose m is big theta of 4 to the power n, but still find difficult to prove it.

[image]

Thanks of @LutzL's suggestion. I thought of stirling's approximation before. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *O*-part should be easy. Choosing exactly *n*/2 elements out of *n* is a special case of choosing arbitrary combinations out of *n* elements, i.e. deciding for each of these *n* elements whether to choose it or not.

The *Ω*-part is harder. In fact, [plotting 4<sup>*n*</sup> / binomial(2 *n*, *n*) for moderately large *n*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4%5En+%2F+binomial(2*n,+n)+for+n+from+0+to+1000) I see no indication that this would flatten to stay below some constant. Speaking intuitively, the larger *n* is, the more special is the case when you take a random pick from *n* elements and coincidentially happen to choose exactly *n*/2 of them. That probability should tend to zero as *n* increases, meaning that 2<sup>*n*</sup> should always grow faster than *n* choose *n*/2. Are you certain you understood this part of your task correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. To be honest, I am not sure the lower bound of 2^n is correct. Is there a lower bound that you can think of ?

Comment: But I saw the bound of 2m choose m, which seems to have higher and lower bound of constant times 4^n.

Comment: Per Stirling formula, one can see that `binom{2n}{n}=Theta(4^n/sqrt(n))`. The square root factor makes the requested lower bound impossible. As you can test via WA http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4^n+%2F+sqrt%28n%29+%2F+binomial%282*n,+n%29+for+n+from+0+to+1000

Answer (score 3):

It's not -- it's Theta(2^n/sqrt(n)), and in fact choose(n, n/2) ~ 2^n/sqrt(pi * (n/2)) as n->infinity). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 2):

You could use Stirlings formula for the factorials.

```
n! = sqrt(2*pi*(n+theta)) * (n/e)^n
```

where `theta` is between 0 and 1, with a strong tendency towards 0.

Comment: Thanks, but with Stirling's formula, I still can not prove the lower bound. Any  suggestion?

Comment: @xxx_yyyy Note that this is *equality*.  So `theta == 0` is a lower bound, and `theta == 1` is an upper bound.

Comment: You can not prove the lower bound since it is wrong. As you already found out, it has to be in terms of `2^n/sqrt(n)`.