# Disproving asymptotic lower bound of central binomial coefficient

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, binomial-coefficients

I was recently learning about binomial coefficients and was wondering about how to disprove 2nCn (or the central binomial coefficient) not being lower-bounded by 4^n; in other words:

[image]

Some extremely generous bounds can be easily constructed, such as the following:

[image: eqn1]

I sought to prove by contradiction, so to assume:

[image: eqn2]

Clearly, c<sub>1</sub> cannot exist, since 1/(2n + 1) approaches 0 as n approaches infinity. It can also be seen that c<sub>2</sub> must reside in (0, 1]. And... I'm stuck. Intuitively, it seems rather obvious that c<sub>2</sub> cannot exist.

I am aware a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558086/how-to-prove-binomial-coefficient-is-asymptotic-big-theta-of-two-to-the-power-n), but there wasn't really a proof provided. I'm also aware that you could prove the limit of 2nCn/4<sup>n</sup> approaches 0 as n approaches infinity, but I was wondering if there was another way to do so - particularly, by proving that c<sub>2</sub> cannot exist.

Comment: The question really belongs to [math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com). That said, `4^n` is so _generous_, that `c*4^n` will eventually outgrow the binomial coefficient no matter how small `c` is (so yes, it cannot exist). People chose `c = 1`, for the inequality to hold even for `n == 1`.

Comment: The easiest approach is to write the `choose` in factorials and use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation to prove that the central coefficient is actually `O(2^n / sqrt(n))`.  If you do it carefully you are on your way to proving some special cases of the central limit theorem.

Comment: Oops, I meant `O(4^n / sqrt(n))`.  The peak for `n choose m` is `O(2^n/sqrt(n))` but your `n` is `2*` the one that I was thinking of.

Comment: @user58697 I definitely agree with you, but I'm seeking something more formal. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll try posting it to math exchange.

Answer (score 3):

For all n, the constant c<sub>2</sub> would have to be upper bounded by

```
2n choose n       (2n)!
----------- = -------------
    4^n       2^n n! 2^n n!

                  (2n)!
            = -------------
              (2n)!! (2n)!!

              (2n-1)!!
            = --------
               (2n)!!

                 n    (2i-1)
            = product ------
                i=1     2i

                 n
            = product (1 - 1/(2i))
                i=1

                 n
            ≤ product exp(-1/(2i))    [since 1 + x ≤ exp(x)]
                i=1

                   n
            = exp(sum -1/(2i))
                  i=1

            ≤ exp(-ln(n+1)/2)    [since sum ≤ integral of increasing fn]

            = 1/√(n+1),
```

hence it cannot be positive.